# Sums of Threshold Indicators of Multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional multivariate normal vector $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}({\boldsymbol \mu}, {\boldsymbol \Sigma})$. I am interested in the vector of threshold indicators $\mathbf{z} = (\mathbb{I}\{x_i > 0\})_{i=1}^n$. In particular, I am interested in the sum $S = \sum_{i=1}^n z_i$.

Obviously, $S$ would have a $\mathrm{Binomial}(n, p)$ distribution for $p = P(x_i > 0)$ if $x_i$ are i.i.d. What is the distribution for more general $\mathbf{x}_i$? Can we make statements about the case where $\mathbf{x}_i$ are identically distributed but not independent? That is, where $\mu_i = \mu$, $\Sigma_{ii} = \sigma^2$, and $\Sigma_{i \neq j} = \rho$ for arbitrary $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\rho$, respectively?

Comment: I sorry that there's combinatoric complexity in the covariance matrix that might make any restatement not much simpler than the definition. Consider the case that $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 \ll 1$, with either exact correlations or anti-correlations ($\rho = \pm \sigma^2$) -- S could be (very nearly) zero if there are any such anti-correlations.